# How can I implement cross domain measurement in native Android and iOS apps using the Firebase SDK?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have seen websites using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker to implement cross domain measurement. Is it possible to do something similar with native iOS and Android apps using Firebase SDK. In the app I'm working I'm opening a website own by the company.

According to the documentation by Google `_ga`query parameter contains the client ID as well as the current timestamp and browser metadata encoded within it. If this is not something available in the native Firebase SDKs then I'm open to generating it manually if someone knows how to. However, I want to avoid passing clientId, timestamp and device meta data as query parameters to [manually handle cross domain measurement in the website](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) as it is not recommended by Google.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Nope. I also didn’t look recently.

Comment: Will let you know if I find anything. Dealing with the same issue right now.